JsonConverter does not work when data is received from Form
I have added a custom json converter to trim all strings coming to the web api during de-serialization, like this
options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new TrimStringJsonConverter());

And this works perfectly fine for all the web api's where I read data from request body using [FromBody] decorator but does not work when I read the data from Form using [FromForm] in my web api.
So basically it works for this web api where I am reading data from body
[HttpPost("fund/add-update")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseDto<string>>> AddUpdateFund([FromBody] AddUpdateFundDto fund)
{
}

But does not work for this one where I am reading data from Form
[HttpPost("fund-house/add-update")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseDto<string>>> AddUpdateFundHouse([FromForm] AddUpdateFundHouseDto model)
{
}

It looks like it is by design, because forms are not serialized the way models are serialized.
But still asking, is there any way to make it work for form data also?
Update
This is how I am preparing data to send to the AddUpdateFundHouse web api from my angular code
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', this.addFundHouseFormControl.id.value);
formData.append('shortName', this.addFundHouseFormControl.shortName.value);
formData.append('fullName', this.addFundHouseFormControl.fullName.value);
formData.append('logoImage', this.selectedLogoImage);

this.adminService.addUpdateFundHouse(formData);

And this is admin service code that finally calls the web api
addUpdateFundHouse(dto: FormData) {
    return this.http.post<IResponse<boolean>>(`${environment.apiUrl}/admin/fund-house/add-update`, dto)
        .pipe(map((response) => {
            return response;
        }));
}


Uh... form posts are not JSON. Why would a JsonConverter even be involved?

@ProgrammingLlama Understood. Then is there any way to configure it for forms also at the central level, same like we do for json?

I suspect that you are sending the request body as JSON instead of form data when calling the AddUpdateFundHouse API after you change it to accept the request body as form data (multipart/form-data). Please share the code how you send the request.

The only way that comes to mind (if you only want to trim values) is perhaps to write a middleware that checks the content type and goes through the form. This would have to happen before model binding.

@YongShun - No, I am sending it as FormData only. Updated the question with the details of how I am preparing the data for this web api call in my angular code

@PawanNogariya Forms don't use JSON, so there's no point in talking about JSON or stuff "like" JSON. If you don't use an HTML FORM though, why not post the data as JSON using fetch? Check the code in this MDN example.

@PawanNogariya besides, you posted only the code that creates the FormData object, not the code that sends it. It's quite likely the code doesn't make a proper form post

@PanagiotisKanavos Updated the code. Please check

Disclaimer: It seems that you want to trim strings in a form post prior to binding them to a model. I could be wrong about that intent.

Middleware Solution
One way you could do this is to create a middleware to pre-process the request for form posts and trim the values:
public class FormValueTrimmerMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        // check that it's a form post
        if (context.Request.HasFormContentType)
        {
            // trim and save the values to a dictionary
            var fields = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();
            foreach (var key in context.Request.Form.Keys)
            {
                var trimmedValues = context.Request.Form[key].Select(v => v.Trim()).ToArray();
                fields[key] = new StringValues(trimmedValues);
            }

            // replace the existing form with the one with trimmed values
            context.Request.Form = new FormCollection(fields, context.Request.Form.Files);
        }
        // call the next middleware in the chain
        await next(context);
    }
}

Register it as a service:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<FormValueTrimmerMiddleware>();

Then you can register it at startup:
app.UseMiddleware<FormValueTrimmerMiddleware>();

Note: This will process all form values, since we can't determine if they are intended to be string or not. I can't think of an obvious case where this would pose a problem. Also, this will be applied to every single controller and action.

Filter Solution
As a filter, this can selectively be applied to specific controllers or actions, rather than to all form requests.
public class TrimFormValuesAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAsyncResourceFilter
{
    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext resourceContext, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var context = resourceContext.HttpContext;
        // check that it's a form post
        if (context.Request.HasFormContentType)
        {
            // trim and save the values to a dictionary
            var fields = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();
            foreach (var key in context.Request.Form.Keys)
            {
                var trimmedValues = context.Request.Form[key].Select(v => v.Trim()).ToArray();
                fields[key] = new StringValues(trimmedValues);
            }

            // replace the existing form with the one with trimmed values
            context.Request.Form = new FormCollection(fields, context.Request.Form.Files);
        }
        // call the next middleware in the chain
        await next();
    }
}

Usage:
[HttpPost("fund-house/add-update")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[TrimFormValues] // Apply the filter
public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseDto<string>>> AddUpdateFundHouse([FromForm] AddUpdateFundHouseDto model)
{
}

